# Subprocess and hardcoded directorys work fine varables fail

Tags: python, django, subprocess, wlst

So am running into an issue and now sure what I am doing wrong. I am using python 2.4 and the subprocess module. This is integrated with my django site. I have a form that askes for some user input, it puts that into a file then starts the script with the directory the file(s) are in.

If I hardcode the directory in the string it will work fine, and out put the wlst script, if I do not it will not work and just connected and think that it is done.

Still stuck with no information. Onto why. The script works fine normal command line, and even from normal python code. The only thing I could tell is with the variables.

Code:

```
if form.is_valid():
                        env = form.cleaned_data['env']
                        user = form.cleaned_data['user']
                        group = form.cleaned_data['group']
                        role = form.cleaned_data['role']

                        id = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(6))

                        root = "/opt/tools/Mapper/output/webui/%s" % (id)

                        if not os.path.exists(root):
                                os.makedirs(root)

                        output = open(root+"/mapping.out", 'w')

                        if (user):
                                user_stg = "User:"+user+":"
                                password = User.objects.filter(user__contains=user).values('password')

                                password_f = open(root+"/passwords.out", 'w')

                                password_out = "%s:%s" % (user, password[0]['password'].encode('ascii'))

                                password_f.write(password_out)
                        if (group):
                                grp_stg = "GroupName:"+group+":"
                        if(role):
                                role_stg = "RoleName:"+role

                        out_stg = user_stg+grp_stg+role_stg

                        output.write(out_stg+"\n")

                        command = "/opt/tools/Mapper/bin/wlst /opt/tools/Mapper/bin/creator -e ldap.dev -s pacdcespopsa1:7001 -o /opt/tools/Mapper/output/webui/JBHSMN"

                        args = shlex.split(command)

                        print args

                        resp = HttpResponse(command_output(args));

def command_output(args):
    import subprocess
    return subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

The only difference between this code and the varable driven one is that I have for

```
command = "/opt/tools/Mapper/bin/wlst /opt/tools/Mapper/bin/creator -e ldap.dev -s pacdcespopsa1:7001 -o %s" % (root)
```

Comment: why in your code command is hardcoded and root is randomly generaed?

Comment: Its only hardcoded in the first example to show that it works. It randomly generates a directory for each use so that people dont over write and you can use it incase the web ui fails and you can see what someone has done.

Comment: i've just noticed that changing hardcoded example to variable-driven will lead to differernt result, won't it?

Comment: exactly and that is what I am trying to figure out why it is doing that

Comment: but `id = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(6))` in general generates different string while command is fixed. When using root variable command changes the same way and corresponds to `root`. Does it make sense?

Comment: No it doesnt, even when I run it the args from shlex look like this. ['/opt/tools/Mapper/bin/wlst', '/opt/tools/Mapper/bin/creator', '-e', 'ldap.dev', '-s', 'pacdcespopsa1:7001', '-o', '/opt/tools/Mapper/output/webui/1CXQ2M']

Comment: so it works fine if I remove the .communciate()[0] it runs in the background fine. Is there any other way I can get it to grab the output?

Comment: I believe I am faceing the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422775/subprocess-popen-hangs-with-interactive-programs-when-called-from-inside-django